# How to make random combination not to repeat?

Tags: php, random

I'm working on already made Facemash-Alike Script. It's script that shows two pictures, and user make a choice which picture is better for him.

I wanted to create a small improvement that **won't show a user the same combination of two pictures he already voted**.

I tried to do this in two ways. But any of this ways is not good enough or not comfortable for user.

*First one* - Choices of two pictures are randomized. After vote, in database, new record is created with this specific combination, and value of vote. If combination of two pictures already exist as record in database then page shows historical vote, and after few seconds page refreshing, making another random combination.

*Second one* - In the moment when names of pictures are added to database then scripts creates all possible combinations as records in database. It's good way, because script pulls out from database a random record that doesn't contains any result, and after vote saves with a value. So it's no way to make any repeats. The main problem of this way is in the moment of adding new pictures. Database at the start becoming huge, and creating all possible combination at start taking forever.

Because of that I'm looking for another solution. I would like to hear even small advice that might help find me a way.

Comment: I would have done it like you did in the "first one", except maybe generating a new pair immediately (repeatedly?) instead of showing the historical vote and reloading.

The second solution is not very efficient, like you already discovered. If your database is that big, maybe you don't need to make this small improvement at all, since the chances of having the same pair showing up will become smaller and smaller?

Comment: The first one is non deterministic. For the second one you missed one important fact (or I got it wrong): you have to create those combinations for each user. This results in n * (n-1) * u records. Which might explode your database. Could give the information if users and pictures are constant? In which order of magnitude are pictures and users?

Comment: User is one (different databases, decentralization). Number of images is variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first approach scales better, you just want to avoid showing an historical vote. You need to keep a history of votes anyway, so use that history as a filter. In the SELECT statement you are using to get the random faces, left join on the history table to use the join as a filter.

Example:

```
SELECT faces.uid f_uid, votes.uid v_uid FROM faces 
LEFT JOIN votes ON votes.user_id=# AND faces.uid=votes.face_id1 AND            
faces.uid=votes.face_id2 
WHERE v_uid IS NULL
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2
```

That will make sure they never see the same face twice. It will become slower the more faces a user votes on. It won't be noticeably slower until they have done many hundreds of votes.

That said, you could change the LIMIT to something like 20 and cache that (i.e. in the session). You then have the next 10 pairings (20/2=10) ready to go. That is sort of a combination of 1 & 2.

Comment: It's interesting idea. Could you give me an example of constructing a database query for that case? I wonder if such query will become slower noticeably after some time.